# value in hidden field in form without generating action

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem :

If I have three checkboxes with different values on a form like :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1stValue">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2ndValue">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3rdValue">
```

And I needed to submit that form so that the values end up in a hidden field
called ans with an , in between each, so that the text field
on the same form has in effect '1stValue , 2ndValue , 3rdValue' 
contained within it withpur generating action on form.

Which is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "without generating action on form"?

Comment: without submitting the form.........

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a function that will put the comma separated values inside hidden field before submitting form.

Check this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setHiddenField()
{
    len = objForm.elements.length;
    var i=0;
    var hiddenValue='';
    for( i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
    {
     if (objForm.elements[i].type=='checkbox' && objForm.elements[i].checked==true) 
        hiddenValue += objForm.elements[i].value+",";
    }
    if(hiddenValue!='')
       hiddenValue = hiddenValue.substr(0,hiddenValue.length-1);

    document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId').value = hiddenValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="objForm" >
<input type="text" name="checkboxes" id="hiddenFieldId" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1stValue"><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2ndValue"><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3rdValue"><br/>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="setHiddenField()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Note: 
I have put input type="text" to show that the values are coming right, change it to hidden in your actual code
Also I assume you need to get value of every checkbox in the form

Comment: yes i requires the same thing which you are saying but it doesn't work if i use this function on on click option

Comment: @ritu Don't forget to accept nik's answer - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

put the checkboxes in an array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1stValue">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2ndValue">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3rdValue">
```

then on the next page implode the array

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkboxes" value="<?php echo implode( ',', $_POST['checkbox'] ) ?>">
```

Comment: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars(implode(',', $_POST['checkbox'])) ?>` Please always recommend a defensive approach, XSS attacks are so common because so many people get this basic thing wrong: *All values MUST be HTML-ecoded before they are output to the page.*

Comment: agree, just didnt feel the need to complicate the answer with other subjects

Answer (score 0):

You can either create multiple hidden textboxes and put one on each, Or use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1stValue">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2ndValue">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3rdValue">
```

With this serverside:

```
<?php
$data=implode(",",$_POST['checkbox']);

echo "<input type='hidden' value='{$data}' name='hiddenField' />";
?>
```

Comment: its works only on generating action....i want this value in hidden form field without generating action on form......

Comment: what do you mean by generating action?